# Odoo 7 get always wrong active_id in rml header

Tags: header, odoo, rml

I want print 2 or more odoo 7 reports in the tree view together in one pdf file.
I need  output shopdata in the rml header on my own picking report. 
I got the shop data of the last object on all pages, because inside the rml header the active_id is for all objects the id of the last object not of the current object.

How can i fix this?